# Is it possible to safely eject flash drive from Emacs

Tags: microsoft-windows, process

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1.
If I want to safe eject usb flash drive I use this (on system tray)

[image: Safe_eject]

Is it possible to do this in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is recommended [in this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/443162/remove-usb-device-from-command-line), you can use a free command line tool, [RemoveDrive](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html), and launch the command from an emacs session or from within a shell buffer.

> RemoveDrive prepares drives for "Safe Removal" by commandline. It works with drives only but not for other device types.